# SIGBART with cellviewwithtag

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I was wondering why I get a SIGBART error on this code. I have assigned a tag for each the image and button but I still get an error. Does anyone know why this might be?

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cat") as UITableViewCell!

    let image = cell?.viewWithTag(1) as! UIImageView //the error is here
    image.image = UIImage(named: "CatIcon")

    let button = cell?.viewWithTag(2) as! UIButton
    button.setTitle("Cat: \(CatView.catsnum[indexPath.row])", for: .normal)
    button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: Font, size: 20)
    button.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(CatLink), for: .touchUpInside)
    button.backgroundColor = .black
    button.backgroundColor?.withAlphaComponent(0.5)

    return cell!
}
```

Comment: Is `cell` nil? If not, is `cell?.viewWithTag(1)` nil?

Comment: Are you sure you've given the imageView tag 1?  What does `print(type(of: cell!.viewWithTag(1)!))` print?

Comment: Please, don't use `tags`, they are a poor substitute for outlets.

Comment: @Sulthan I’m probably going to change it later. I’m just temporarily using it to link so I can get a sort of draft of my app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to register the tableView with the cell

```
tableView.register(customClassName.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cat")
```

Or this with xib

```
tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "customClassName", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier:"Cat")
```